# Permissions issue on external drive after reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I have had to reinstall windows, but am now unable to read or edit certain documents on my external drives that I set up before the reinstallation.
I have set file permissions for `Everyone` manually, but I am told that I need permission from the main user account `Rick`, and when I go into the file permissions for the file I see that this account and an Administrator account are listed twice with identical names. I wondered whether the problem is that there is a remnant of the user account from my previous installation and windows needs permission from that account. Can anyone suggest how I can test this and how I can rectify it if it is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you get prompted to enter credentials?

Comment: No, I just get told I need permissions from whichever user/usergroup I've set as the owner. I think that despite the unhelpful errors the problem may actually be because the file was encrypted by windows, but the certificate was lost when I had to reinstall windows. All the problem files are marked as encrypted and I can't decrypt from the context menu or using the cipher function in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Open ***Local Security Policy*** -> ***Security Options*** and open ***User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode***.

[image]

Now select ***Prompt for credentials*** option and save.

[image]

Now try opening the external drive, you will be prompted to enter credentials. Enter credentials in this format:

- Username: ***<OLD_PC_NAME>\<old.username>***
- Password: ***oldpassword***

Comment: Thanks Zoran, I will try this is as soon as I have chance (currently moving house).